# Pentaho AWS S3 File Output Server Side Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pentaho

Pentaho AWS S3 File Output component does not support SSE - has anyone faced this issue?  If so, is there a (Pentaho) solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it doesn't support encryption. Best solution would be to use the shell script. It will take all the parameters like S3bucket, access key, secret key, s3 path. Encryption will be done using KMS, which will be a .jar file. Using the shell script you can directly pull and push the encrypted files to/from S3.

Here's the sample of what you can do in a shell script to achieve it:

```
java -jar /root/etl/lib/key-file.jar -accessKeyId $1 -secretKey $2 -KMSKeyId $3 -targetBucketName $4 -targetS3Prefix $5 -srcFile $6 -srcType $7 -hdfsLocation $8  -tmpDirPath $9 -jobName ${10}
```

Comment: @Pasha: I have tested it and it works perfectly. Give it a try and accept my answer if it helped you!